# Managed driver for MS Access

Tags: .net, ms-access, driver

MS Access files can be read using JET or the newer ACE. Both of these are native drivers, i.e. they have to be installed. Oracle databases can be queried using native drivers (Oracle Client) or managed .NET drivers (ODP.NET). Is there such a thing as a managed .NET driver for MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a managed provider called ODBC.NET, and it ONLY been tested with SQL server, Oracle, and Access/JET.

However despite being a “managed” .net provider, it still requires that the Access ODBC provider ALSO has to be installed. (So you don’t get around this issue – at least in the case of Access). So an un-managed code driver is assumed to exist on windows in the case of JET.

Of course in windows, both SQL server and JET providers ARE installed by default out of the box. Thus in theory you would not have to install anything additional.

So keep in mind that windows includes the JET provider that can read “mdb” files, but not accDB files which would require you to install the ACE database engine.

The above .net “managed” driver ONLY works because windows includes the un-managed Access drivers by default.

I am not 100% sure of this in regards to SQL server, but again it suggests that the managed SQL driver works because it uses the built in un-managed drivers that windows provides by default. So I can’t confirm this for SQL server, but I can for Access/JET.

So in regards to Access/JET you WILL be using SOME un-managed code despite the fact of not having to install anything in regards to reading mdb files – but for accDB format files, you will have to include the ACE connectivity components.

And the ODBC.NET provider while managed code STILL assumes that you using the defaulted install of un-managed JET drivers for mdb files, or in the case of "accdb" files, then it is assumed you have installed the ACE drivers. No matter how you slice and dice this, you might not have to install anything, but in ALL CASES you still be using some un-managed code that is assumed to exist on your computer - and this means that such drivers will have to match the bit size of your .net project.